# How to generate every combination of a given pattern in numpy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a constraint variable based on which I need to generate every combination possible in a numpy array.

```
 length = 12
 x >= 4 , x <= 7
 Solution:
 array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],
        [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
        ..... <every possible combination>
       ])
## I tried the below way but I am not sure how to obtain the desired result
np.tril(np.ones((12,12),int))
```

The sum of 1 within an array should be between 4 and 7. The length of one dimensional array or list should be 12 and the values of 1 should not be disjoint i.e. [0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0] is not valid since the pattern of 1 is interrupted by 0 . This one is valid : [0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]

I need to this in the most efficient manner. Can someone please guide. thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly. Are you looking for every possible binary vector of length `length` with a sum between x_min and x_max?

Comment: You should edit the question @user1596433 to include this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any special function but test(...), below, runs in 149us on my machine.  If you use the result a lot save it and copy from it as required.

```
def n_ones_in_len( n_ones, length ):
    """ Returns a diagonal with n ones offset by one column in each row. """
    n_rows = length - n_ones + 1
    res = np.zeros((n_rows, length), dtype = np.int)
    for start in range(n_rows):
        res[ start, start : start + n_ones] = 1
    return res

n_ones_in_len(4,12)
Out[5]:
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Use this function to define a function to generate all the required quantities of ones.

```
def test(lo, hi, length):
    """ Returns a numpy array with diagonals of lo to hi-1 ones in rows of length columns """
    res = np.empty((0,length), dtype = np.int) # Initialise res
    for ones in range(lo, hi):
        res = np.vstack((res, n_ones_in_len(ones, 12)))
        # Stack the new results to the res array
    return res

test(4, 8, 12)  # Note half open range.
Out[8]:
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       ...
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

There will be other ways of doing this which may be faster but this should be reasonably easy to follow.