# How to optimize following function in python?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, optimization

I have function which right now takes anywhere between 15 min to 20 min to run. I am using it multiple times in an algorithm and currently the algo. is unusable because of the time consumed. Is there anyway the following function can be optimized :

```
def find_all():
    for x in range(4, 10):
        for y in range(4, 10):
            for z in range(4, 10):
                for z1 in range(4, 10):
                    for z2 in range(4, 10):
                        for xs in range(13 - x):
                            for ys in range(13 - y):
                                for zs in range(13 - z):
                                    for z1s in range(13 - z1):
                                        for z2s in range(13 - z2):
                                            a = np.zeros(12, int)
                                            a[xs:xs+x] += 1
                                            a[ys:ys+y] += 1
                                            a[zs:zs+z] += 1
                                            a[z1s:z1s+z] += 1
                                            a[z2s:z2s+z] += 1
                                        if 0 not in a:
                                            yield x, y, z,z1,z2s,xs, ys,zs,z1s,z2s,a

%time list(find_all())
```

Basically what I am trying to do here is to build a list where there is no zero left. I did try the below solution but it only works for two ranges and I have a requirement where I might need upto 6 ranges
[How to generate every combination of a given pattern in numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56712422/how-to-generate-every-combination-of-a-given-pattern-in-numpy-array/56724620#56724620)

Comment: Can you please explain *what* it is doing? What *pattern* do you aim to create?

Comment: You're doing something like 100 million iterations (I'm not sure how to calculate the exact number of iterations, because of the dependencies in the inner loops on the values of the outer variables). If you really need that many operations, it's going to take a long time.

Comment: Not to seem rude, but this would probably be answered quicker at Stack Exchange's "Code Review" site which is mostly for optimizing working code like you have here. Stack Overflow is more for helping fix non-working code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.product` on all of the ranges to more easily generate your index values.  This will reduce the coding overhead.

Next, note that you have a *very* regular sequence of overlapping ranges.  You should be able to *derive* the minimal interval coverage, rather than painstakingly re-computing it from each group.  Check first to see whether all elements are covered before you go through the process of computing the values via increment.

Note that the five pairs of parameters are entirely interchangeable.  You can reduce a *lot* of searching if you quit wasting time finding equivalent solutions.

Does that get you moving?